# Pick the first of two asynchronous futures to complete

Tags: scala, monads

Is there a scala combinator for combining two futures as follows

```
val Comb[A]: (Future[A], Future[A]) => Future[A] = 
 (f1: Future[A], f2: Future[A]) => Future {
    if f1 succeeds before f2 then f1
    else f2
 }
```

while discarding the second future before it completes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Future.firstCompletedOf(...)`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$@firstCompletedOf[T](futures:TraversableOnce[scala.concurrent.Future[T]])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[T]) does exactly this.

For what you are trying to do:

```
def Comb[A](f1: Future[A], f2: Future[A]): Future[A] = 
   Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(f1, f2))
```